# Nginx headers not recognized properly

Tags: security, nginx, header

The headers are not recognized by mozilla observatory. Any ideas?

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors 'none'";
add_header X-Frame-Options: DENY;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the `:` for a start.

It may not be necessary but I escape my `'` instead of mixing and matching `"` and `'`.

Mine looks like this and works:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy 'default-src \'self\' *.example.com; report-uri ....';
```